# iOS5 Second View Controller

Tags: ios5

I'm trying to create a second view controller and link it to a new set of .m & .h files then alter the text of a label on that view controller under the viewDidLoad but am having some issues.

Here's what I am doing so far.

1. I'm starting with a blank new single page, from the MainStoryboard, I add a new VC and add buttons so I can navigate between the pages. This works fine.
2. Next I create a new Objective-C Class, "SecondViewController" and choose subclass UIViewController.
3. Now back on the Storyboard I select the other ViewController and try to pick the new SecondViewController as a Custom Class but it doesn't show up in the list of available classes.

Now, if in step 2 I choose the UIView subclass I can assign it to the ViewController in step 3 but the viewDidLoad options are not available so I am not sure how to program changes to the VC.

What am I missing here?

I am able to use the UIView and use the following to make the change I am asking about. I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    myLabel.text = @"change2"; 
 }
```

EDIT ----

Okay, I've figured it out. I was clicking on the VC's View (background) in the Storyboard and not the actual ViewController! Now it works the way I thought it should. I suppose if I had looked at the View Controller Scene I would have noticed what I was doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, if in step 2 I choose the UIView subclass I can assign it to the
>   ViewController in step 3 but the viewDidLoad options are not available
>   so I am not sure how to program changes to the VC.

The class of your ViewController (or similar one) from interface builder and another class in your code must extend the same class